# Why isnt global working in an exec command?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, global

this is my code. I basically created a function that generates lists automatically depending on the length of a pandas table. The function takes in a pandas table as input and you need to specify what column you want the rows to be converted into lists (column_name) and the function basically executes the lists automatically. The code is all working great, however, there is a problem. I want each and every generated list (i) in the for loop to be a global list. so I have tried putting exec(f'global {i}') in the loop in an attempt to make all the lists global.

A solution was to put the whole block of code outseide the function and it will work fine, however, I really need the code to be in a function. Any advice on how to make every generated list a global list using exec(f'global {i}')??

Thanks

```
def auto_generate_lists(x):
namesoflistssss1=[]
names_of_listsss = []
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    names_of_listsss.append(f'ls{i}')

for i,j in zip(names_of_listsss,range(0,len(x))):
    exec(f'global {i}')
    exec(f'{i} = []')
    exec(f"{i}.append(x['column_name'][{j}])")
    exec(f"namesoflistssss1.append('{i}')")
```

Comment: @bauman.space: What? No, that's completely unlike how Python's `exec` works.

Comment: @bauman.space but it works ..